# Setting line height in table created using flextable inserted into powerpoint using officer

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I have drafted some dataframes with text inside that linebreaks are present in each cell, the dataframe is converted to `flextable` and then inserted into a powerpoint slide using `officer`. I found the line height a bit too much, I tried using the `height_all` function in `flextable` to make reduce the line height, but it is not working. Please find the sample code as below:

```
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

pptx.output.st00 <- read_pptx()

data(iris)
data.df <- head(iris) %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  mutate_all(.,as.character) %>%
  mutate_all(.,~paste0(.,'\ntesting'))

pptx.tbl <- data.df %>%
  flextable %>%
  height_all(height = 0.01) # this line is not working

pptx.output.st01 <- pptx.output.st00 %>%
  add_slide(.,layout = 'Title and Content',master = 'Office Theme') %>%
  ph_with(.,value=pptx.tbl,location=ph_location(type='body'))

print(pptx.output.st01,'presentation.output.pptx')
```

Currently I need to manually change the paragraph settings for table as the screen capture below:

[image]

Is there a way in `officer` of `flextable` to set up line height for table? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't satisfied by this ad hoc way, but `padding(padding.top = 0, padding.bottom = 0.5)` and `height_all(0.45)` gives a bit better output.

```
pptx.output.st01 <- pptx.output.st00 %>%
  add_slide(.,layout = 'Title and Content',master = 'Office Theme') %>%
  ph_with(.,
          value=pptx.tbl %>% 
            padding(padding.top = 0, padding.bottom = 0.5) %>% 
            height_all(0.45),
          location=ph_location(type='body'))
```

[image]

Comment: The padding adjustment is working, meanwhile is there anyway to adjust the line spacing? Thanks!